# Navigation links wont change back to original color

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Whenever i click on a link it should turn green showing that you are on that page, all other links are supposed to be blue until a new link is selected and then whatever link you click on is supposed to be green and the link you were just at should turn blue but as of now all the links will stay green even after selecting a new page.

This is my CSS page:

```
body{
background-color:#ffffcc;
color:#003300;
font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
background:url(images/primehorizontal.png);
}
h2{
color:#003366;
}
h3{
color:#006600;
padding-top:10px;
}
dd{
font-style:italic;
font-size:.90em;
line-height:200%;
}
#header{
color:#48751A;
}
.nav{
font-weight:bold;
font-size:1.2em;
}
.contact{
font-weight:bold;
font-size:.90em;
font-family:"Times New Roman",helvetica,serif;
}
#footer{
font-size:.60em;
font-style:italic;
clear:both;
}
#wrapper{
width:80%;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
background-color:#ffffcc;
min-width:700px;
padding:0px 0px 20px 30px;
border:1px ridge #00332B;
border-radius:15px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 3px 3px #00332B;
-moz-box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 3px 3px #00332B;
box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 3px 3px #00332B;
}
img{
border-style:none;
}
#left{
float:left;
width:150px;
}
#right{
margin-left:180px;
padding: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
#left ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}
#left a{ 
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: center;
color: #FFFFCC;
border: 3px outset #CCCCCC;
padding: 5px;
}

#left a:visited { background-color: #48751A; }
#left a:link { background-color: #003366; }
#left a:hover { border:3px inset #333333; }

.floatleft{
float:left;
padding:0 20px 20px 0;
}
.clear{
clear:left;
}
```

Here is my index page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<title> Prime Properties</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="prime.css">

</head>

<body> 

<div id="wrapper">

<h1 id="header"><img src="images/primelogo.gif" alt="prime logo" height="100" width="650"></h1>

<div id="left">

<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="listings.html">Listings</a></li>
    <li><a href="financing.html">Financing</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</div>

<div id="right">

<p>Prime Properties is prepared to market and sell your property.</p>
<p>The philosophy of Prime Properties is to promote our clients, not ourselves.</p>
<p>We can also help you find the property that meets your needs:</p>

<ul>
    <li>location</li>
    <li>price</li>
    <li>features</li>
</ul> 

<br>

<div class="contact">Prime Properties<br>
3055 Bode Road<br>
Schaumburg, IL 60194<br>
<br>
847-555-5555<br>

<br>

</div>


<div id="footer">

<div class="nav">

<a href="index.html">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="listings.html">Listings</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="financing.html">Financing</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="contact.html">Contact</a>

</div>


Copyright &copy; 2013 Prime Properties

<br>

<a href="mailto:joshua392141@aol.com">joshua392141@aol.com</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Visited links are green because you have `a:visited` set to green.  So long as that link was recorded in your browser's history, it'll be that color.

Comment: Well i knew a:visited was set to green but how would i get it to behave so that the current link you are on is green while the rest are blue? Do i have to somehow make the links reset? Once you select a link it should turn green while any other previous page you were on should turn back to blue @MikeChristensen

Answer (score 0):

```
#left a:visited { background-color: #48751A; }
```

This makes links that you have visited green. When you close the site again, it is still in your browser history which makes the link still appear green.

If you want the colour to go back to blue again once you close the page you're going to have to use javascript/jQuery. I don't think you can do that with css/html alone.

Comment: The only problem is that im not allowed to use javascript/jQuery for this. It has to all be in HTML5

Answer (score 0):

First, forget about using `:visited` at all.  It doesn't do what you think it should do.

You'll probably need to edit each page and add a selector for the current link.  For example, `index.html` would look like:

```
<a class="current" href="index.html">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="listings.html">Listings</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="financing.html">Financing</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
```

`Listings.html` would look like:

```
<a href="index.html">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a class="current" href="listings.html">Listings</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="financing.html">Financing</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
```

Then, in your CSS you'd have:

```
a.current { color: green; }
```

This could also be done with a server-side language like PHP or ASP.NET.